Noble: Nautilus goes into infinite loop while browsing an NFS share whose permissions change
can be recreated as follows:

own an NFS share
access it through the Files application (Other locations > nfs://192.168.1.12/path/to/share > Connect)
change the permissions (e.g. disallow connections from IP or on a certain port; or disallow the user)

observe:
an infinite growth of modal windows telling you that it cannot access the mountpoint, but they keep on growing until they eventually use all RAM and crash this or that program. A way out is to ctrl-alt-F1, log in to a text shell, ps aux | grep nautilus and kill <PID>.
Should I report this bug against gnome or against ubuntu?

Yes, write a report this issue as a bug.
